# Problema ao atualizar pip no CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pip

[image: MD]
estou tentando utilizar Robot Framework e um dos passos é fazer funcionar esse pip no cmd....

Comment: A resposta está equivocada, Veja a tradução do texto acima: *DEPRECIADO: Python 2.7 alcançou o fim de sua vida em 1 Janeiro de 2020. Por favor atualiza o seu Python pois o Python 2.7 está descontinuado. pip 2.0 irá remover o suporte para Python 2.7 em Janeiro 2021. Para mais detalhes sobre o suporte Python 2 no pip podem serem encontrados em https://pip.pypa/............(url no final da frase)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu pip está na última versão, ou seja, já foi atualizado. O comando `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` não surte efeito quando seu pip já está na última versão.